# How to change the display of the description from another attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes

For main website example: `mywebsite.pl`  - A short description of the product is displayed from the attribute `short_descrption`.

[image]

For other websites stores I want to change display short description from other attributes.

**Example:**

for website `mywebsite.com` I want to display product short description from attribute: **`english_short_description`**

for website `mywebsite.cz` I want to display product short description from attribute: **`czech_short_description`**

Any solution on how to do in product layout?

New update:

Please check, our code now get duplicate short description: (because we didn't overwrite the code - we just added it above.
And now two codes are responsible for downloading the descriptions.)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
if($_code == "short_description") {
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $storeCode     = $storeManager->getStore()->getCode();

    if($storeCode == "english") {
        $_call = 'getEnglishShortDescription';
        $_code == "english_short_description";
    }

    if($storeCode == "czech") {
        $_call = 'getCzechShortDescription';
        $_code == "czech_short_description";
    }
}
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

$renderLabel = true;
if ($_attributeLabel == 'none') {
    $renderLabel = false;
}

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div class="product attribute <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_className ?>">
    <?php if ($renderLabel): ?><strong class="type"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeLabel ?></strong><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeAddAttribute ?>><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeValue ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
$themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data');

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>
<?php if($_attributeValue): ?>
    <?php if($_className == 'overview'): ?>
        <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/short_description')): ?>
            <div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
                <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
                <div class="value std" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php elseif($_className == 'sku'): ?>
        <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/sku')): ?>
            <div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
                <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
                <span class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
            <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none' || $_attributeLabel != __('none')): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
            <span class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

here is our original file from template vendor (our file looks little different from the original magento file attribute.phtml. So I think to our original code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
$themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data');

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>
<?php if($_attributeValue): ?>
    <?php if($_className == 'overview'): ?>
        <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/short_description')): ?>
            <div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
                <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
                <div class="value std" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php elseif($_className == 'sku'): ?>
        <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/sku')): ?>
            <div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
                <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
                <span class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
            <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none' || $_attributeLabel != __('none')): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
            <span class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

we need only implement this rule:

```
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
if($_code == "short_description") {
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $storeCode     = $storeManager->getStore()->getCode();

    if($storeCode == "english") {
        $_call = 'getEnglishShortDescription';
        $_code == "english_short_description";
    }

    if($storeCode == "czech") {
        $_call = 'getCzechShortDescription';
        $_code == "czech_short_description";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create `english_short_description` and `czech_short_description` attribute for product and assign in particular attribute set

And you need to override the `attribute.phtml` file under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

and use the code below:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
if($_code == "short_description") {
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $storeCode     = $storeManager->getStore()->getCode();

    if($storeCode == "english") {
        $_call = 'getEnglishShortDescription';
        $_code == "english_short_description";
    }

    if($storeCode == "czech") {
        $_call = 'getCzechShortDescription';
        $_code == "czech_short_description";
    }
}
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

$renderLabel = true;
if ($_attributeLabel == 'none') {
    $renderLabel = false;
}

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div class="product attribute <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_className ?>">
    <?php if ($renderLabel): ?><strong class="type"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeLabel ?></strong><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeAddAttribute ?>><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeValue ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Flush magento cache and check

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Our file looks little diffrent. Can you please check our update?

Comment: You don't need any change in html structure. just put condition above your code and change storeCode as per your store

Comment: Ok, I add above, but now I see the same double short description. So I think we need implement this rule to our file code we add in topic. Can you please check again? Thank you. https://e-gerris.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/90145/s/m83n00-f7v3/

Comment: Sorry i have checked code. but i m not able to check condition as per your code. bcoz i don't have configuration and all. You have to check your conditions why it happened

Comment: Let me know have u changed anything in layout file for short description?

Comment: This happened because we did not overwrite this file - we just added the code to the file at the very top. And it looks like these two codes get the description twice. So I think we should only add this one rule: if ($ _ code == "short_description") {.... to our code which is in the subject of the message. Please check my update within one moment

Comment: You wrote 2 times same code that's why it happened

Comment: Yes, because If we paste only your code this format <li> no work etc: https://prnt.sc/q1n84n so, if is possible can you please help us impletement this rule directly to our orginal file code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101454/discussion-between-naresh-rupareliya-and-sylvester).